# Play 2.2 - Evolutions - multiple databases

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-evolutions

I have a Play 2.2.1 application that connects to multiple databases.  One database is a read/write database and one is a read-only database.  In development mode, I would like to configure my application so that evolutions are executed on the read/write but not the read-only database.

So far, I've only been able to enable/disable evolutions for all databases using the "evolutionplugin={enabled/disabled}" setting.  Is it possible to enable evolutions for one database but not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible at the moment.  See [this thread.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/Ce1f0vH8H_w/reOrFQKPlcUJ)